# fetchResultController get NSInvalidArgumentException swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

basically i want to fetch all object in that entity
i'm calling this method in viewDidLoad()

```
func updateUI() {
    if let context = container?.viewContext {
        let request:NSFetchRequest<Reminder> = Reminder.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: title, ascending: true)]
        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try? fetchResultController?.performFetch()
        remindersCollectionViewController.reloadData()
    }
}
```

title is String? entity name is "Reminder"
currently no object in coredata

when excute this line of code

```
fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

the app crashes and i got the error

```
2018-06-13 12:14:25.345072+0800 Reminders[25712:3061130] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

appreciated any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks odd here is that `title` is a String? in your sort descriptor. In most use cases the sort descriptor is fixed so you should do (assuming there is an attribute `title` for `Reminder`)

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
```

or even better, use #keyPath

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Reminder.title), ascending: true)]
```

If I am wrong and title is a variable that can change between fetches then at least unwrap it before using it

```
if let sortKey = title {
     request.sortDescriptors...
}
```

Comment: kind of awkward...turn out just forgot put quotation marks...thank you very much